python_folium。can't change color
    multipoints = folium.GeoJson(device_geometry.to_json(), style_function=lambda feature: {'color': 'red'})
    d = folium.FeatureGroup(name='device')
    d.add_child(multipoints)
    m.add_child(d)

my program can show multipoint in layer，but show blue
I try many methods，always be blue
method:
multipoints = folium.GeoJson(device_geometry.to_json(), style_function=lambda feature: {'color': 'red'})
d = folium.FeatureGroup(name='device')
d.add_child(multipoints)
m.add_child(d)
